# E-mail with 404 URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found

I just got the email about being one of the *Top new Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange users for the week*. It linked to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/cstheory/2011-04-18, which 404s.

Answer (score 2):

I guess they meant https://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/week/cstheory/2011-04-17

Edit: This got fixed by 301 redirect now.

Comment: Hum, I searched your name "Tim", you are not there. that could be another bug.

Comment: only users with > 200 rep are tracked in the leagues.

Comment: But, @Jeff, only such users would get the email too, right?