# What was the reason to change ids in the links to reputation leagues?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, reputation-leagues

[Reputation leagues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/reputation-leagues/info) are located at the url `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/{id}` where the number at the end of the url determines the site. You can find reputation league for example at the bottom of [users tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users).

The numbers of the page with reputation league has changed for some sites - probably not too long ago. What was the reason for doing this?

My impression that the fact that old links no longer work might cause slight problems, since there may be plenty of links using the old ids. (For example, in posts on meta illustrating some bug in reputation league.) Are there maybe some plans to update links automatically (in the same way it was - at least in some places - done with [http to https](/q/292058) conversion)?

---

I have checked that using 1, 2, 3 as id leads to leagues for the original trilogy. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1 https://stackexchange.com/leagues/2 https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3. So I assume they were not changed.

But it is not difficult to find many examples where there was a change. At the moment if you look at [leagues in Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://stackexchange.com/leagues), almost all links there will give you 404 error if you try to click them. (I suppose the version cached by Google will be eventually updated, but it is easy way to check this now.) In Wayback Machine I found [a snapshot from January 31](http://web.archive.org/web/20180131160958/https://stackexchange.com/leagues) which still has old ids, while [on February 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20180201170436/https://stackexchange.com/leagues) you can already see the new ids. (So the change seems to be very recent.)

Some examples of sites where the id has changed and I found also some post which also links to the old id:

- Ask Different: The id [is now 118](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/week/apple) but it used to be 46. (See the post [Most Active Contributors Quarterly Report - 4th Quarter 2017](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3188) on the local meta.)
- Mathematics: The id [is now 69](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69) but it used to be 21. (See [an answer on local meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/sum-of-reputation-on-created-on-m-se/25829#25829) from February 2017.)
- MathOverflow: The id [is now 504](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/504/week/mathoverflow) but it used to be 251. (See [post on local meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3497/an-error-in-calculations-of-percents-in-reputations) from December 2017 linking to the league with the old id.)
- Physics: The id [is now 151](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/151/week/physics) but it used to be 62. (It is linked in [this answer on local meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9650/open-justice-v-secret-police/9653#9653).)
- Science Fiction & Fantasy [the id is now 186](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/186/week/scifi) but it used to be 82 (as mentioned [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/39179?m=42173429#42173429) in January 2018.)

Comment: ugh. Coulda sworn I saw a mention of it being changed before - either in relation to the HTTPS switch or SEDE

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I was able to find only this question from 2011, which mentions a link where id is not a number but site name: [E-mail with 404 URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88713). Most likely it is not what you meant. But at least from that post I have learned that I can omit the number completely and the link still works.