# Why the links with "leagues/{site-name}" do not work for all sites?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, reputation-leagues

Typically when you go to reputation league, the url looks something like `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/{id}/{site}` or `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/{id}/{site}`, etc. The link contains some numerical value followed by site name, for example `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/stackoverflow`.

Since those numerical ids of sites [can be changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306575/what-was-the-reason-to-change-ids-in-the-links-to-reputation-leagues), when posting a link to some information league, the links of the form `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/{site}` might be preferable. And they indeed work (you get redirected to a longer url including the "id"), some examples: [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/stackoverflow), [Super User](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/superuser), [Arqade](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/gaming), [English](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/english), [Ask Different](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/apple), [Server Fault](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/serverfault),... However, the shorter version does not work for [MathOverflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/mathoverflow) - you need to you [a longer url](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/504/week/mathoverflow) which includes the numerical value - which is currently 504.

**Question.** Why the "shorter" link does not work on some sites? Is MathOverflow the only site where the shorter link does not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/mathoverflow.net

The "site name" parameter is actually the [*host* name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) - so Super User is https://stackexchange.com/leagues/superuser.com, English is https://stackexchange.com/leagues/english.stackexchange.com, etc. But that's verbose, so the route accepts shorter names and tries to *guess* the rest of the host name:

```
return SiteByHost(sitename) 
    ?? SiteByHost(sitename + ".stackexchange.com") 
    ?? SiteByHost(sitename + ".com");
```

Ah... But MathOverflow's host is mathoverflow*.net* - and since no other sites have a .net host, nobody thought to try completing the partial name with ".net". Thus, to get to MathOverflow's league, you must specify the entire host name.

**Update:** as of May 23, 2019 `.net` is also checked as a possible domain option.

Comment: I'll add link to this post (which is - to some extent - related): [Why is Math Overflow a .net website unlike all the other sites which are .com websites?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4015)